# Client side database sync for Chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I am writing a Chrome app and I need to be able to sync my HTML5 IndexedDB between a user's devices. Does Chrome sync these like Chrome syncs [storage.sync](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html)? Or is there something else available to use as a client-side database?
Thanks in advance for your help.